# How to generate a a really big Random integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random, integer

I want to generate a 64 bit integer in ruby. I know in Java you have longs, but I am not sure how you would do that in Ruby. Also, how many charecters are in a 64 bit number? Here is an example of what I am talking about... 123456789999.

```
@num = Random.rand(9000) + Random.rand(9000) + Random.rand(9000)
```

But i believe this is very inefficient and there must be a simpler and more concise way of doing it.

Thanks!

Comment: You generally want to inject a seed just once at the start of a program.

Comment: So you want to generate a random number between -2^64 and 2^64 - 1 ? Or you want to generate a random number with X number of digits.

Comment: 2**64 I think would work.

Comment: There's usually context for a random number. What's it for? For instance `SecureRandom.random_number( 2**64 )` would be appropriate if you want to generate a key or secret.

Comment: "How many characters are in a 64-bit number?" That's a problematic question. Character count doesn't have any particular correlation to bitwidth. Plus, it depends on radix. You could store the number 15 _as_ a 64-bit integer, and then the first 60 bits will be `0` and the last 4 will be `1`, but expressed in decimal there's only two characters. Expressed in hex, there's only one character (`F`).

Comment: Adding random numbers produces a non-uniform distribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) can take a range as argument:

```
p a = rand(2**32..2**64-1) # => 11093913376345012184
puts a.class #=> Bignum
```

[From the doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Bignum.html): Bignum objects hold integers outside the range of Fixnum. Bignum objects are created automatically when integer calculations would otherwise overflow a Fixnum. When a calculation involving Bignum objects returns a result that will fit in a Fixnum, the result is automatically converted...